# Should Stack Overflow Allow people to Down/Upvote a Question/Answer if an Accepted Answer is Present?

Tags: feature-request, voting, accepted-answer

I like the up/down vote system. It is a creative way of rating an answer, and it just has Stack Exchange written all over it.

Although, I think if a question is asked well enough for someone to give an answer that works, or if someone comes up with an answer that works, it should not be down/upvoted. If a question gets downvoted after it's an accepted answer than that really makes no sense. It was obviously clear and well thought out of, enough for it to work for that asker.

My question is, should stack exchange be able to downvote accepted answers?

Comment: Are you asking that people not downvote accepted answers or not downvote questions with an accepted answer?

Comment: If this was implemented, people asking bad questions could just blindly accept the first answer they received and freeze any downvoting. That would allow them to circumvent question quality safeguards, and harm the overall quality of content on the site.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that the accepted answer isn't always the right answer.

Comment: It's not that it's a bad question, it's just people disagree with you

Comment: It's just a bad proposal.  I don't even think Shog9 could make this one better...

Comment: No, on meta, votes don't mean it's a good or bad question like on SO. They are used to express agreement / disagreement most commonly. Don't worry about it as much.  Accordingly, they don't lead to question bans (IIRC they still can but the thresholds are extremely high.)

Comment: "My question is, should stack exchange be able to downvote accepted answers?" is exactly what I wanted people to do, not tell them that this is what should happen, I wanted to see what they thought because I wanted to see if this idea was good and consider the factors.

Comment: For the record, I didn't downvote anything because I've been dogpiled before and it sucks.  But I still contend it's just a bad proposal and there's no way to make it a good one without changing your stance.

Comment: ^ and 14 people disagree with the idea of that

Comment: @nathan32100 yes, but it's asked sort of like a feature request, and you tagged it as one. Like I said, don't worry about downvotes on meta nearly so much. Any time you express an opinion people might pile on downvotes if they disagree with it. They're just not as big of a deal on meta.

Comment: @nathan32100 also, this is a pretty okay use of meta IMO. Yes, I do think your proposal is pretty bad. I posted an answer, and enjoyed thinking about it and writing it up enough. If you learn a bit more about how SO works, that's very okay. This is one of those "there are no stupid questions" moments. I think it's much better that you asked and discussed. Please don't let the downvotes dissuade you.

Comment: So how should I edit it?

Comment: All of the above said; may I gently (but strongly) suggest that you may want to have a little bit more experience with Stack Overflow before you continue presenting changes to policies or how the community behaves?

Comment: still waiting for my question ban to lift

Comment: @TheFestivusUnicorn Not only that but reading through previous meta `feature-requests` would be very helpful to see how they are received.  I'm pretty sure something very similar to this has been suggested in the past.

Comment: @nathan32100 I wouldn't. It's not a good proposal, so don't spend time salvaging it. The downvotes don't matter very much. Unicorn is right; it will probably be a while before you can come up with a solid policy proposal here, but if you don't understand a policy and can't find an explanation in the SO blog or on meta then it's fine to post asking about it. Btw, if you tag as "support" instead of discussion or feature request I think the DVs are less harsh, since people are more apt to understand you're asking for explanation.

Comment: If you've been Q-Banned because of this one, it ain't gonna lift until your rep has gained.  Took about 500 or so points to get mine lifted a few months back.

Comment: @JohnnyBones on meta? From what I understand Q-bans on meta are extremely rare.

Comment: Well, it happened to me.  Maybe I'm just **that** special.  :o)  My first few questions here were clunkers, for sure.

Comment: On down voting of accepted answers - for a *long* time, [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/131401/40980) was the accepted answer to the question.  It would have been quite bad for it to not be able to garner downvotes.

Comment: @djechlin It does take a good bit of work to get a QBan on Meta, yes.

Comment: @MichaelT suggest posting that as an answer. makes the point much more succinctly and memorably than mine.

Comment: No, I had one from the first day on Stack Overflow

Comment: @MichaelT I think this post is about the *question* being voted on, though; with the 'trigger' just being that the question has an accepted answer.

Comment: @nathan32100 That is not correct at all. You asked your [first question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20432061/how-do-i-make-it-so-when-i-sign-up-that-account-is-able-to-log-in-to-the-databas) on the 6th, and [your third (10k only)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503309/how-do-i-make-a-stack-overflow-navigation-bar) on the 12th.

Comment: @djechlin I tend to get wordy when I try to be succinct.

Comment: @nathan32100 `still waiting for my question ban to lift` - if you are waiting for your ban to be lifted, generally it will not be.  I only see 1 undeleted question on your account, so you very likely have several heavily downvoted deleted questions.  Until you get those fixed and undeleted, it will be difficult to lift the ban.

Comment: Its not on meta

Comment: For the record, there are two [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503309/how-do-i-make-a-stack-overflow-navigation-bar) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433142/how-do-i-fix-my-mysqli-php-error) (10k only, obviously) One is -14, one -5, both closed. /cc @psubsee2003

Comment: @nathan32100 psub wasn't talking about Meta. You have two undeleted ones here.

Comment: @The Festivus Unicorn This is Meta Stack Overflow

Comment: @nathan32100 I know very well where we are. Everything I said and psubsee2003 said is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What if the accepted answer is wrong and the asker who accepted it is also wrong?  It's up to the community to downvote it so future visitors don't use it.

For instance the accepted answer could work well enough for the asker to use it, but have a gaping security hole.  There are many ways an answer can look good to an asker at the moment but be terrible in the long run.

As for downvoting a question, many bad questions have answers.

- Yes, it is generally a good sign for a question to have an answer. That's why the asker can accept it and get +2 rep. But it's not a terribly strong indicator of question quality. People answer because they get rep anyway especially accepted, it's fun, etc.  In particular there is a large class of bad questions with good answers: very easy questions that could have been solved with a little more research or have very closely related questions on SO. We don't want those - they get answers, but take time from answerers that could have gone elsewhere, and if many users did this SO would become less usable.
- Furthermore, the user may have accepted in error.  In particular if your system were in place, a user could just accept any poor answer to prevent the question's vote count from degrading.
- Downvoting still gives feedback to the asker, can lead to a question ban, and tells future visitors that this question is likely not useful.

Answer (score 6):

### On downvoting accepted answers

There's a question and answer that is a bit (in)famous on Programmers.SE

[Why use try … finally without a catch clause?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/131397/why-use-try-finally-without-a-catch-clause)

The question boils down to why would you ever write `try { } finally { }` that lacks a catch statement.

For a very long time, the accepted answer was:

> Catching errors/exception and handling them in a neat manner is highly recommended even if not mandatory.
>
> The reason I say this is because I believe every developer should know and tackle the behavior of his/her application otherwise he hasn't completed his job in a duly manner. There is no situation for which a try-finally block supersedes the try-catch-finally block.
>
> I will give you a simple example: Assume that you have written the code for uploading files on the server without catching exceptions. Now, if for some reason the upload fails, the client will never know what went wrong. But, if you have caught the exception, you can display a neat error message explaining what went wrong and how can the user remedy it.
>
> Golden rule: Always catch exception, because guessing takes time

Which is, well, wrong.  It wasn't until [September of this year](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/131397/timeline) that the correct answer was accepted.  In that time, the wrong, accepted answer had garnered a score of -63.  Because, well, it's wrong.

By preventing the accepted answer from being downvoted it would have meant that it would instead had a score of +6 and people wouldn't have realized *how* wrong it was.

Granted, a fair bit of that -63 score was likely piling on (and was infamous and showed up when you sorted by votes, reverse).

---

### On downvoting questions with accepted answers

Even if a question has an accepted answer, it may not be a good, useful question to the site.

The mouseover for the downvote on the question reads:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

If I was to write the question "How do I write a hello world program in C" and someone posts the answer which I accept, it doesn't make it *not* a poor question.  It is still something that didn't show any research effort and isn't useful to the community as a whole.

Downvotes serve several purposes.

- Help feed the question ban algorithm.  The question ban algorithm is there to try to keep people from posting questions that consume the community's time without adding value to the site as a whole.
- Help feed the roomba auto delete scripts.  Questions that are negative scored and abandoned or closed can be deleted by the scripts that try to keep the cruft from accumulating.  There are thousands upon thousands of these questions out there that are slowly cleaned up in this way.
- Makes it easier for 10k users to delete questions that are poor.  The higher the total score on the questions and answers, the more votes to delete it takes.

The key point with these is that just because it helped *you* doesn't mean that it is something that helps *everyone*.

A key concept to realize about Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange network is that it endeavors to be a site where people who have a question can search and find an answer to their question.  Sorting out the signal from the noise is a key value proposition of Stack Exchange that sets them apart from the forums.  The way this signal is identified is through votes, both up and down.

Things that help everyone are what Stack Exchange wants to identify and promote when people search for them.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer does not specifically address the OP's question, but is in reference to his SO Q-Ban... unfortunately it was much too long for a comment:

Since you are question banned on Stack Overflow and your comments suggest you are hanging out on Meta, waiting for your ban to be lifted, please let me offer you some unsolicited advice.

Stop waiting and start working.  If you read [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th) you'll know that the ban doesn't time out or go away in time and no one can remove the ban from your account.  The only person that can control whether you become unbanned or not is **you**, and that is by contributing positively to Stack Overflow.  Answering and editing questions can help a little, but one of the best ways to lift the ban is to improve the content that caused your ban.  I suggest you take the 2 links that Festivus provided in his comment:

- [Positioning Words inside a Div Element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20503309/how-do-i-make-a-stack-overflow-navigation-bar)
- [How do I fix my mysqli/php error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20433142/how-do-i-fix-my-mysqli-php-error)

and try to improve those questions so they can be undeleted and will attract upvotes.  I don't have 10K on SO, so I can't see them, and I am only guessing that they are salvageable.  Just based on the title, the first one might not be salvageable but the second one may be, but I am only working off of the titles.

If you aren't sure what you need to do to fix them, I suggest actually using the power of Meta to help.  Constructive meta questions on how to fix up your questions are usually well received and can result in a lot of very good feedback.  You can copy the text of your question into a question on Meta, and ask how you can fix it up.  You'll get a lot of comments, some critical, but most will be constructive criticism.

Then take the advice you are given and edit your question and flag for a moderator to undelete them.  If the question is good enough, a mod will undelete the question.

And if you do manage to get unbanned, you are not out of the woods.  Until you have an extensive history of positive contributions, you may be close to getting banned again, so you need to be careful about posting new bad questions.

Comment: Having actually looked at those questions, the assumptions that you've made about them from the title don't seem particularly accurate.  The first in particular is...pretty bad.  Also, this whole answer is offtopic for this question.

Comment: @Servy it was just a guess based on the titles and the only reason I answered it is there was no on-topic question to address the OP... I figured it was a better solution to redirect the OP's focus than to have him make several poor Meta proposals while he is waiting.... this answer will self destruct when I'm sure he's had an opportunity to read it